# How do I run the same application twice in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ to develop my client-server application and just discovered Compounds. Basically I can run my client and my server at the same time and it's saving me useless manipulations everytime I want to test. However, I would like to test my application with 2 clients and 1 server since it's a game and have no point being played alone. IntelliJ does not let me add the same application twice in a compound. How can I achieve that ?

What I have now:
[image: Compound configuration]

Plus, I can't tell a run configuration to run itself before launch. When I click the button in the following, image, the configuration I am on does not show up.

[image: Can't run itself]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can copy the run configuration of your client, give it a different name and leave all other parameters unchanged. Then you'll be able to select the two copies in the "Compound" run configuration.

Answer (score 74):

Click Run->Edit Configurations.
For the file requiring multiple instances, click on **Allow parallel run**.
You can do this for multiple files.
Click on Apply.
[image]

Answer (score 22):

I had same  problem with Intellij 2018.2.5 and solved it by uncheck "**single instance only**" check box in "run/debug configuration."

By the way each time I run Spring class (that have main method) new instance will be created.

The important point is never forget that we can't run application on same port. so it's necessary to set **server.port = 0** in **application.properties** to run application on random port.
[image]

Answer (score 17):

On Mac:

Go to `Run` > `Edit Configurations...` then select the application. Click the `Modify options` drop-down, and turn on `Allow multiple instances`.

Remember to click `Apply` *then* `OK`.

[image: Image showing setting to turn on]

Comment: @Allema_s Glad it helped because 2 people downvoted this answer for some reason 

Comment: It works on Windows too, thanks for help / IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2

Answer (score 10):

Click on 'Edit Configuration', when the pop-up appear. On the right hand side you wll see check boxes ,one of them says:'Allow run in parallel' - check this one.

Answer (score 4):

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1
Build #IU-232.9559.62, built on August 23, 2023
Click Run->Edit Configurations->Modify Options->Allow Multiple Instances
```

[Run/Debug Configurations->Modify Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efVRI.png)

[Run/Debug Configurations->Modify Options-Allow Multiple Instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XGGT.png)

Answer (score 2):

For windows :

> Firstly Go to the dropdown menu next to the Run/Debug buttons on the toolbar, then select "Edit Configurations...".
> Then do the following :

1. copy configurations while having selected the configuration you need to copy
2. edit the environment variables
3. change the server  port from the original server of the service
4. save the configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find this in Edit Configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, i copy the same configuration [image]

1. I run my first Application.
2. I change the port of something not to be duplicated
3. I run my second Application.

-> It worked well.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Spring Boot Application:

1. Add(or copy) extra Run Configuration "Spring Boot"
2. Name it somehow
3. Copy or check if Main class is from the original configuration
4. Open Environment variables window and add vartiable "server.port" with value witch is different from the original server.port

Run both configurations!

[image: Running multiple instance of spring boot application in Intellij IDEA]

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij:

Click Run->Edit Configurations->Modify Options->Allow Multiple Instances